# Can I create a new table and store the result of the full join of two tables into it in oracle server?

Tags: oracle, join

There are two tables A and B
I did a full join for these two tables and it displayed in a table format.
Can I create a new table and import those results into it so that I can use this table to display its values instead of using the whole code again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do "Create table as SELECT ..."  Refer http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view for that (materialized or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table from any select statement:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE 
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_A
,      TABLE_B;
```